# XSLT Transform output in aspx page is not working in IE11

Tags: xml, xslt, internet-explorer-11

I am using ASPX page to transform XML to XSLT and display output however the chrome and edge is responsive to the aspx whereas IE11 is not responding to any click events of XSLT TRANSFORMED output.

Comment: "to transform XML to XSLT"? Do you transform XML with XSLT to HTML? And if any click events are the problem then it sounds like a browser and/or Javascript problem. Show us a minimal sample of all relevant code to allow us to reproduce the problem together with a more detailed description as to what kind of element (link, button) can't be clicked or doesn't respond and whether the IE 11 error console (open with F12) shows any errors.

Comment: Yes , am rendering the XML via XSLT to HTML and displaying in a aspx page. The link is supposed to open a bootstrap modal which is present in the xslt code. Chrome and Edge is allowing the modal and responding fine however the IE is only displaying the HTML output but you cant do anything on click (link or button)

Comment: And does the error console (F12) show any errors? Does the bootstrap modal work in plain HTML in IE 11?

Comment: Try to use F12 developer tools to check whether it contains some error? Besides, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). According to [this blog](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/manas1/display-xml-data-as-html-using-xslt-in-asp-net/), I have created a sample, it works well on my side, so, I think perhaps the issue is related to your xmlt template. Please try to refer to the blog and check your code.